# $ в названии переменной - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp

При сжатии js скрипта выпадает ошибка:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name ($content)

До сжатия скрипт работает нормально.

```js
(function () {

let $content = $('.s-content');
let $back2top = $('.back-to-top');
let $windowHeight;
let contentBottom;

function onScrollWindow() {
    let offsetY = window.pageYOffset;

    if (offsetY - $content.offset().top > 100 && !$back2top.hasClass('back-to-top_visible')) {
        $back2top.addClass('back-to-top_visible');
    } else {
        if (offsetY - $content.offset().top < 100 && $back2top.hasClass('back-to-top_visible')) {
            $back2top.removeClass('back-to-top_visible');
        }
    }

    if (offsetY + $windowHeight >= contentBottom && !$back2top.hasClass('back-to-top_pinned')) {
        $back2top.addClass('back-to-top_pinned');
    } else {
        if (offsetY + $windowHeight < contentBottom && $back2top.hasClass('back-to-top_pinned')) {
            $back2top.removeClass('back-to-top_pinned');
        }
    }

}

function onResizeWindow() {
    $windowHeight = $(window).height();
    contentBottom = $content.offset().top + $content.height() + 25;
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    if ($content.length < 1 || $back2top.length < 1) {
        return;
    }

    $windowHeight = $(window).height();
    contentBottom = $content.offset().top + $content.height() + 25;

    document.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
        onScrollWindow();
    }, true);

    window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
        onResizeWindow();
    }, true);
}); 
    })();
```

Comment: сдается мне проблема в твоих переменных с долларами.

Comment: Если доллар убрать, ругается просто на content

Comment: Да и чем доллар может не угодить

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в том, что сжимальщик не понимает es6, в частности твои `let`

Comment: Довольно интересно, учитывая, что сборщик сам проверяет на es6 и не дает использовать var.

Comment: В общем консоль обнаружила странную ошибку типа
a.indexOf is not a function
    at r.fn.init.r.fn.load
В следствие чего, переменные не записываются (скрипт не выполняется дальше)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский переменные с долларами тут не причем. Виноват был let

Comment: @Grundy Действительно, let не распознавался

Answer (score 0):

Для ES6 можете использовать `uglify-es`, так он будет правильно сжимать файлы

```
let gulp = require('gulp'),
uglifyes = require('uglify-es'),
composer = require('gulp-uglify/composer'),
uglify = composer(uglifyes, console);

gulp.task('js:vendor', function () {
    return gulp.src('paths-to-src')
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('paths-to-dest'));
});
```